# Как сделать картинку больше?

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте! У меня есть ImageView и две картинки(маленькая и большая) с разным отношением сторон. По нажатию на кнопку картинка меняется. Как мне сделать вторую картинку больше и отодвинуть кнопку вниз на такое же расстояние как между первой картинкой.(Как отодвинуть кнопку понял, но размер картинки не могу изменить)

Comment: приведите пример кода, что уже пробовали

Comment: поменять `frame` у ImageView

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Comment: `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);`

Comment: А можно изменить высоту ImageView с помощью nslayout? Если можно, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Если используется `autolayout`, то для изменения размеров элемента (в данном случае картинки)

1. Создайте `constraint` (если еще не существует), который задает высоту картинки
2. Создайте `@property` для этого констрейнта, примерно так будет выглядеть

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageHeightConstraint;
   ```
3. Для изменения высоты элемента задайте в коде новое значение констрейнта, когда это необходимо

   ```
   self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = newValue;
   ```